# Add all columns of original data frame to the result of do

Tags: r, dplyr

**Code**

Suppose I have a `tibble` which contains both atomic vectors and objects:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
(mdat <- data_frame(n = 2:5, mod = rep(list(lm(rnorm(10) ~ 1)), 4)))

# # A tibble: 4 × 2
#       n      mod
#   <int>   <list>
# 1     2 <S3: lm>
# 2     3 <S3: lm>
# 3     4 <S3: lm>
# 4     5 <S3: lm>
```

Now I want to use `do` to create a new `data.frame`:

```
ndat <- mdat %>% rowwise() %>% do(data.frame(mod2 = I(list(lm(rnorm(.$n) ~ 1)))))
```

**Question**

If I want to keep the original columns I see 2 possibilities:

1. Add the columns explicitly in the `do` call:

   ```
   (mdat %>% rowwise() %>% 
       do(data.frame(n = .$n, mod  = I(list(.$mod)), 
                              mod2 = I(list(lm(rnorm(.$n) ~ 1))))))
   # Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
   # Groups: <by row>

   # # A tibble: 4 × 3
   #       n      mod     mod2
   # * <int>   <list>   <list>
   # 1     2 <S3: lm> <S3: lm>
   # 2     3 <S3: lm> <S3: lm>
   # 3     4 <S3: lm> <S3: lm>
   # 4     5 <S3: lm> <S3: lm>
   ```
2. Add an artificial `id` column and join the data frames (output stripped):

   ```
   left_join(mdat %>% mutate(id = 1:4), 
             ndat %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(id = 1:4), by = "id")
   ```

Option 1 is error prone, because I have to hard-code all columns of `mdat`. Option 2 introduces a meaningless `id` column.

My question is: can I achieve the desired output directly via `do`? My first thought was to use

```
mdat %>% rowwise() %>% do(data.frame(., mod2 = I(list(lm(rnorm(.$n) ~ 1)))))
```

But this does not work because of column `mod`:

```
# Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
#   cannot coerce class ""lm"" to a data.frame
```

So do I have to rely on option 2, or is there a better way (better in the sense of avoiding additional columns and hard-coding columns)?

Comment: according to the above link: `mdat %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(mod2 = list(lm(rnorm(.$n) ~ 1)) )`

Comment: Perfect thanks that did the trick!